# sed: get last n character in every matching line

Tags: string, sed

so i have a file like that:

```
bla bla bla 
telephonenumber: 497621160119286
y y y    
xxxx   
telephonenumber: 4160119100
xxxx   
blabla 
telephonenumber: 160119126
```

I need to change the given file to that:

```
bla bla bla 
telephonenumber: 9286
y y y    
xxxx   
telephonenumber: 9100
xxxx   
blabla 
telephonenumber: 9126
```

Basically just get the list 4 Character of the number in a matching line

I figured out something like that:

```
sed '^telephonenumber:/s/^.*/(.\{4\}\)$/1\' givenfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sed 's/^\(telephonenumber: \).*\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1\2/' file
```

or using extended regex

```
sed -r 's/^(telephonenumber: ).*([0-9]{4})$/\1\2/'
```

There are 2 capture groups. `\1` refers to your search pattern and the `\2` matches only the 4 last digits of the number.

Comment: Very Nice. The first line worked really well for me! Thank you:*